# How can i use JSR 172 in Android?

Tags: android

I want to use `JSR 172 API in android`.

But supports core `java`,is it possible to use `JSR 172` in android.

Please give some code snippets or suggests any web sites to learn about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that JSR 172 is for J2ME (CDC and CLDC) devices and Android is not J2ME so you need to check Android documentation to see if there are similar classes that allow the feature that you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can move the jsr-172 reference implementation classes over.